# US Visa requirements when living in Caribbean

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, esta

I will be moving to and living in the French Caribbean for 6 months. I have an EU passport so my stay there is covered by that. I don't know how we are getting there yet, but there is a high possibility that we will have to transit through America.

I have a valid ESTA for visiting the US for tourism purposes but reading the terms, they group neighbouring countries and the Caribbean into your 90 day maximum stay. It does say that this doesn't apply to Caribbean residents.

While living there, I will probably make a few short (1-2 week) visits to the US to visit friends.

If I am living in the French Caribbean, ie. it is not a visit for tourism purposes, do I need to go to a US embassy and get a full transit/tourist visa, or will my ESTA be enough?

As an EU citizen, I don't legally have to register as a resident in France but would this be advisable to make (re-)entry in the US less painful?

Answer (score 2):

Your ESTA is fine, but do bring some documentation proving you do live in the French Caribbean. Make it abundantly clear, if need be, that the French Caribbean is covered by European Union rules, i.e. you have freedom of movement and need no visas or permits whatsoever (or even a passport) even to settle there for life.